# Programmatic installation of application + Change default message + Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an application where we don't want to put the application on Google Play, so the application and update of application is on our server.

Now, when we update the application programmatically after downloading it from server, Android shows a message by default that is "Replace application message: The application you are installing will replace another application. **All previous user data will be saved.**".

[image: message]

In our application we flush app database so the previous user data will be lost for this particular application, so in this case I want to remove or change above message.

Could you please help me how can I change this default message?

My code for re-installation is as follows:

```
public static boolean install(Context context, String downloadPath){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPath+"/"+"MYAPP.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(intent);
    Log.d("INSTALLATION DONE", "***App installed");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please help me how can I change this default message?

Step #1: Download the source code to the Android OS from http://source.android.com

Step #2: Modify the OS to remove this message

Step #3: Package your revised OS into a modded ROM for the device(s) that you will be distributing to users of your app

Step #4: Install that modded ROM on those devices

IOW, this message is not being displayed by your app, but by the OS itself, and you cannot change that behavior from your app.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, Thank you for your reply, is there any way or intent to go to the next message directly, or override this message, cause change is OS is fine the updated OS also needs to share with customers and that'a a bit complicated.

Comment: @Ishand: "is there any way or intent to go to the next message directly" -- no. "or override this message" -- I provided general instructions for this in my answer. "cause change is OS is fine the updated OS also needs to share with customers and that'a a bit complicated" -- yes. Perhaps you should reconsider your approach of "flush app database so the previous user data will be lost for this particular application".